# What's the purpose of TR-069 in a CPE ONT device?

Tags: networking, router, remote-access

I understand that TR-069 is a means for (typically an ISP) or other parties to remotely manage a router/ONT. Apart from the obvious benefits that come from being to remotely diagnose network issues faced by a customer, what other functions does TR-069 serve?

Is it possible to still have an internet connection by disabling TR-069?

For context, I have an ONT in bridge mode with the NAT function disabled (handled by my own router). Hence, I'm looking to disable all internet facing services on the ONT device and let all internet routing be handled by my router for security purposes.

Comment: Wiki explains what other functions a TR-069 can serve https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TR-069#High-level_operations_possible_through_TR-069

Comment: @gantendo Thank you, that was helpful. Going to try disabling it and see if my ISP allows a connection. Would an ISP still be able to remotely access my modem if I disable TR-069?

Comment: You can use your own modem & router, and store theirs in a cardboard box (they probably own it and you probably have to return it at some point). Or use this method https://security.stackexchange.com/a/93521 ISPs use TR-069 to control the devices they hand out to their customers, but I can not prove there is no other backdoor (the firmware is closed source). There could be, in theory. You may be able to disable TR-069; it shouldn't affect your ability to connect to the internet.

Comment: @gantendo Yeah, that's what I've done. Put the ONT in bridge mode and I'm using my router to do the NAT. It'd be great to completely ditch the ONT, but the ISP doesn't allow it. And from some threads on here and on other forums, what I get is that for fiber optic ONTs, replacing the ISP provided ONT is hard to do or almost impossible. You got any experience or guides here?

Comment: Not really to be honest.